# How to send notification from other website to facebook android app? It shows on the website. But not on the app

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

```
$response = $fb->post(
    '/'.$username.'/notifications',
    array (
      'href' => '?true=43',
      'template' => $string
    ),
```

what should I write in the 'href' tag?

Comment: Up to you. It'll be passed along to your Facebook app. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications

Comment: Does your app have an Android version …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the docs:

> The notifications are only surfaced on the desktop web version of Facebook

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications

Comment: why not on messenger?

Comment: that is just how it is, and what the docs say about it. about the "why" you would have to ask facebook directly.